# Undo Point while Adding Circular String

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to undo the curve while editing or undo a point where you accidentally placed it? Sometimes I accidentally place a point where I didn't mean to while in edit mode for "add circular string" and I can't undo the point. The only way is to end the point and delete the curve. In ArcGIS you can click a point and undo immediately but I can't seem to find a way to do this in QGIS.

Comment: Does backspace work?

Comment: backspace doesn't work when i try it says "No Feature Selected"the current layer has no selected features". I know that using backspace for "Add Line Feature" works

Comment: Can you finish editing the curve, then select and delete the point with the Vertex Editor tool?

Comment: I can finish editing the curve and then delete points, but the problem is when I finish editing the curve it'll show all the points on the curve. What I want to do is delete the point before I finish editing the curve. To make the curve it's a 3 point click, so if i didn't click on the spot on the second click I want to delete that 2nd point to place it on another spot

Comment: It's not an "undo", but pressing "escape" cancels that curve and avoids having to delete the unwanted feature.

Comment: Oh, I tried that and it does work. What if I'm making more than one curve? Is there a way to cancel out the next curve instead of clearing all the curves?